# Doesthis argument prove that circle is an $\mathbb R$-vector space?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, vector-spaces

I'm going to make the unit circle $S^1$ into a vector space. I made the following proof which seems to work well. Just wondering if also you think so. Please let me know if you think there is any flaw in it.

> Define the equivalence (binary) relation $R\subseteq \mathbb R \times
>   \mathbb R $ such that: 
>     $r_1 R r_2$ iff $r_2-r_1=2k\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$.
>
> Then we will have $\{[r]: 0\le r \lneq 2\pi \}=\{[r]: r\in \mathbb R
>  \}$, which means that:
>
> (**)  $\forall r\in \mathbb R \ \exists!  r_0 \in [0,2\pi) \ s.t \
>  [r]=[r_0]$.
>
> On the other hand, we know that $S^1=\{e^{i\theta}:0\le \theta \lneq
>  2\pi \}$. We are going to make $S^1$ into a vector space. So we define the required operations as bellow (all that I've done above this line is in order to avoid going beyond $[0,2\pi)$):
>
> $+:S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$ such that $(e^{i \theta},e^{i
>  \phi}) \mapsto e^{i (\theta + \phi)_0} $, where $(\theta + \phi)_0$ is the unique number obtained due to (**).
>
> Also, let
>
> $\bullet: \mathbb R \times S^1 \to S^1$ be such that $(r,e^{i
>  \phi}) \mapsto e^{i (r \theta )_0}$, where again $(r \theta )_0$ is the unique number 
>    obtained due to (**).
>
> Besides, define $\mathcal 0:= e^{i . 0} = 1_{\mathbb C}$ as the zero of
>    the (to be!) vector space, and for a $v \in S^1$, let $-v:=e^{i \psi_0}$ such
>    that $\psi_0$ is obtained by (**) and we have
>    $(\theta+\psi_0)_0=\mathcal 0$.
>
> Then we have the following lemma:
>
> ***lemmaa***: let $(-)_0: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $(r)_0$ is the unique number obtained due to (**). Then we have:
>
> 1- $\forall \theta_1, \theta_2 \ \in S^1 \ \forall r \in \mathbb R \ \
>  (r_0 \theta)_0=(r \theta_0)_0=(r_0 \theta_0)_0$
>
> 2-$(\theta_1 +\theta_2)_0=((\theta_1)_0 +(\theta_2)_0)_0$.
>
> This seems quite obvious if you work on the unit circle and a few examples of $\theta , \phi$ s and their corresponding  $\theta_0, \phi_0$s on it. That's why I didn't try rigor about it!
>
> Now we prove that $(S^1, +, \bullet)$ is an $\mathbb R$-vector space.
>
> *Proof:* Suppose $v_1=e^{i \theta}, v_2=e^{i \phi}$ for some $\theta , \phi \in [0,2\pi)$.
>
> 1- $r\bullet(v_1+v_2)=r\bullet(e^{i
>  \theta}+e^{i \phi})=r\bullet e^{i (\theta +\phi)_0}=e^{i (r(\theta
>  +\phi)_0)_0}=e^{i ((r\theta_0) +(r \phi_0))_0}=e^{i ((r\theta_0)_0 +(r \phi_0))_0}=e^{i ((r\theta_0)_0} + e^ {(r \phi_0))_0}=r\bullet e^{i
>  \theta_0}+r\bullet e^{i \phi_0}=r\bullet e^{i \theta}+r\bullet e^{i
>  \phi}=r\bullet (v_1+v_2).$
>
> where all of the equalities are applied as results of the lemma, and the last equality holds because we supposed that $\theta, \phi
>  \in S^1$.
>
> 2- $1 \bullet v_1 = 1 \bullet e^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta}=v_1$
>
> 3- ...
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

I didn't write down more. it's going to be such a mess! However, it works pretty well for the other items to be proven.

So, what do you think? Is there anything missing from the proof, or any flaw that I can't see?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

If you restrict $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ (as in your post), "scalar multiplication" fails to distribute over "addition" of angles (!) thanks to "overflow". Compare, for example,
$$
r(\pi + \pi)_{0} = r(0)_{0} = 0 \neq (2r\pi)_{0} = \bigl((r\pi)_{0} + (r\pi)_{0}\bigr)_{0},\quad 0 < r < 1.
$$
(I haven't carefully enumerated all the axioms that fail, but this isn't the only one.)

If instead you allow the exponent $\theta$ in $e^{i\theta}$ to attain arbitrary real values, then scalar multiplication isn't well-defined, since multiplication by $r$ does not preserve the equivalence relation $R$. Concretely, for example, $e^{2\pi i}$ is the zero element of your space, but $r$ times the zero vector, $e^{2\pi ri}$, usually is not.

Comment: Any idea how I can change this to a vector space?

Comment: I mean by a formulation similar to what I presented

Comment: Briefly, "you can't": The circle is an Abelian group, just like the set of vectors under addition in a vector space. To define scalar multiplication, however, you have to define $rv$ for every real number $r$ and every vector $v$ in a manner compatible with the group operation (e.g., so that $2v = v + v$). But the circle (as a group) contains elements of finite order. For instance, $v = -1 = e^{\pi i}$ has order two, i.e., $v + v = 0$ (in the proposed vector space). If there were a scalar multiplication operation, you'd have $$-1 = v = \tfrac{1}{2}(2v) = \tfrac{1}{2}(v + v) = 0.$$